# WinJS NavBar event handler crashing Windows 8.1 HTML5/JS app when navigating to another page

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I am developing an HTML/JS app for Windows 8.1 and am having trouble debugging a crash that is ocurring on within a handler attached to the top NavBar object when the user navigates from the page the handler is attached to.

The functionality is pretty simple:  when the user lands on the screen in question, I am automatically displaying a WinJS Flyout using it's .show() method.  Now, when the user invokes the top NavBar object, I have a handler that hides the Flyout object.  I also have another handler that .shows() the Flyout when the NavBar is dismissed.

The problem occurs when the user navigates to another page.  Here is my code for the screen in question:

```
var appBar = class.that.constructs.NavBar;

ready : function (element, options) {

    var self = this;

    ...

    appBar.topControl.onbeforeshow = self.hideFlyout;
    appBar.topControl.onbeforehide = self.showFlyout;

    $('#flyout').addClass('activated');
    $('#flyout')[0].winControl._sticky = true;
    $('#flyout')[0].winControl.show();

},
hideFlyout: function() {

    $('#flyout').topControl.winControl.hide();
},
showFlyout: function() {
    $('#flyout').topControl.winControl.show();
},
unload: function () {
    appBar.topControl.onbeforeshow = null;
    appBar.topControl.onaftershow = null;
}
```

As you can see, I am removing the event handlers upon unloading the page, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  I still get this crash error:

```
 JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'classList' of undefined or null reference
```

It crashes on the `showFlyout` handler.  Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to avoid the crash upon navigating to a new page?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? (Step into it?) What's the callstack look like at the time of crash?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I did try that.  As I stated in my original post.  The program crashes at the line within the `showFlyout` handler.  The callstack states that before it crashes at that line of code, it shows [External Code].  Not sure what that means.

Comment: You didn't state what you'd specifically tried. "Debugging" is a very general term. Can you step-into the `show` function?

Comment: Good point.  No, I have not stepped into .show().  I will do that, and report back.

Comment: After stepping into the .show() method, the issue is, in fact, as Maurizio points out in his suggested answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @ariestav very good, can you accept the answer then?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark I would like to, but it didn't solve the issue.  In fact, you can call the .show() method without an element.  Even when I  passed an element in, the program would crash saying that the element was not available.

Comment: try to pass an element that IS available. if you use the code I suggest, the myButton should not be null.

Comment: I think that's the whole problem.  The .show() method is being called in an event handler that navigates away from the current screen.  There is no available element to pass.  I concluded that it cannot be done in the way I implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The show methos of the flyout wants an element as a mandatory parameter, it is the element it will be attacched to.

in your case you have to find an element and pass it to your function, for example:

```
var myButton= document.getElementById("myButton");
$('#flyout').topControl.winControl.show(myButton);
```

Check this page for a more extensive example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but since the user is already navigating away from the screen that has the flyout, what element do you suggest I send it?

Comment: any element will do, but it's mandatory, if you don't put it you get an error. It's as simple as that.